# Write c++ program to solve eq of e^(x/2)=2sin(x) from 0<X<2

Tags: c++

This is What I have done so far. I'm unable to get the second root(solution). I don't know what to do to continue with the loop once I got the first answer.
Please help me.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double x, y, y0;
    double dx = 0.01;
    const double EulerConstant = std::exp(1.0);

    x =dx;
    y= sqrt(pow(EulerConstant,x))-2*sin(x);
    y0=y;

    while (y*y0>0)
    {
        y0=y;
        x += dx;
        y = sqrt(pow(EulerConstant,x))-2*sin(x);
    }


    cout << "x =" << x << "\n";


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Do you understand how does the algorithm work? Have you tried running it with a bit different startup conditions?

Comment: Not related to your problem, but why not replace `pow(EulerConstant,x)` with `std::exp(x)`?

Comment: Also note that `sqrt(std::exp(x)) == std::exp(x/2)`.

Comment: Do you know what the answer is suppose to be? Also what do you mean by "unable to get the second square root"?

Comment: @JohnOdom He doesn't mean the square root, he means the second *solution* of the equation. There are two solutions, the program will compute only the first. (Solution of equation = *root* of the function when you subtract both sides of each other)

Comment: @leemes Oh okay, I just read that part wrong, my bad, lol.

Answer (score 0):

With this equation, you are going to have a precision problem.  The zeros of this equation are  close to x = 0.90 and x = 1.32, but not close enough that a comparison to a value of `epsilon` would offer you a single good value for either ([Example](http://ideone.com/NL3m8L)).  You'll neither need to increase the precision of your step (e.g. 0.0001 - which I've done in the example already), or store the values of each iteration and do an approximation when the value switches from negative to positive (or positive to negative).

Comment: thanks for answering. the problem i have is that once I find the first solution Im not able to get the second solution. I don't know how to program that second part

Comment: The example I linked gives you both answers.  They key is that you cannot stop once you find a solution (you have to keep going through the whole range).